# Parse GATE Document to get Co-Reference Text

Tags: java, reference, annotations, text-mining, gate

I'm creating a GATE app which used to find co-reference text. It works fine and I have created zipped file of the app by export option provided in GATE.

Now I'm trying to use the same in my Java code.

```
    Gate.runInSandbox(true);
    Gate.setGateHome(new File(gateHome));
    Gate.setPluginsHome(new File(gateHome, "plugins"));
    Gate.init();
    URL applicationURL = new URL("file:" + new Path(gateHome, "application.xgapp").toString());

    application = (CorpusController) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromUrl(applicationURL);
    corpus = Factory.newCorpus("Megaki Corpus");
    application.setCorpus(corpus);

    Document document = Factory.newDocument(text);

    corpus.add(document);
    application.execute();
    corpus.clear();
```

Now how can I parse this document and get co-reference text?

Comment: What about: `URL applicationURL = new File(gateHome, "application.xgapp").toURI().toURL()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know about yours, but co-references created manually using the Co-reference Editor are stored in a **document feature**. The feature name seems to be `"MatchesAnnots"` and the type `Map<String, List<List<Integer>>>`.

In my case, following code prints `as name: null` (the default annotation set) followed by all co-reference chains present in it.

```java
Object obj = document.getFeatures().get("MatchesAnnots");

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, List<List<Integer>>> map = (Map<String, List<List<Integer>>>) obj;

for (Entry<String, List<List<Integer>>> e : map.entrySet()) {
    System.err.println("as name: "+  e.getKey());
    for (List<Integer> chain : e.getValue()) {
        System.err.println("chain : "+  chain);         
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. This is correct. I got it yesterday. I forgot to update here. Anyways appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have any idea about sentiment analysis using GATE? Please share me.

Comment: @Vaisakh Not much, there are some 3rd party plugins (e.g. https://github.com/gsi-upm/SAGA ) and the Training Course - Opinion Mining presentation, which includes also a machine learning approach https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/TrainingCourseJune2014/