# GATE MatchesAnnots Feature Output

Tags: gate

I'm attempting to perform coreference using the GATE `MatchesAnnots` document feature, and I get the following output:

```
{null = [[866, 871, 872], [869, 873, 877, 879], [874, 895, 896]]}
```

Can anyone help me understand what this means? I'm assuming each of these arrays are each a coreference chain - but what are the numbers? Character start numbers? I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question

> what are the numbers?

### Answer

They are GATE **annotation ids** of the chained annotations.

### Explanation

GATE document feature `MatchesAnnots` contains a map ( `Map<String, List<List<Integer>>>` ) with following content:

- Each **key** correspond to the name of corresponding `AnnotatienSet`.
- Each **value** is a list of all the coreference chains.
- Each **coreference chain** is a list of **ids of annotations** belonging to the chain.

### See also

- [Parse GATE Document to get Co-Reference Text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27035648/1857897) (similar SO question)
- [GATE Annotations](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch5.html#sec:corpora:dags) (official documentation)